# How do I test the display of my laptop ACER 5740

Tags: laptop, display

I mean I believe that drivers are not installed properly for some reason though it shows as proper . The problem is that when I watch movies like IMAX I find that DELL Laptops display much better . Does ACER Compromise on the LCD ? Its ACER ASPIRE 5740 .

Comment: Define "proper" and "better"

Answer (score 0):

Use [DisplayMate](http://www.displaymate.com/).

> DisplayMate produces a complete set of state-of-the-art proprietary
>   test and calibration patterns  together with expert information,
>   advice and guidance to setup, calibrate, tweak, optimize, test,
>   evaluate and  improve the image and picture quality and color and gray
>   scale accuracy of all Monitors, Projectors and HDTVs.